# eBay PHP HTTP POST Request?

Tags: php, http-post

at the moment I am coding an article/customer/billing software with PHP and this is my last step before letting my partner test it.

I'm really stuck at the moment. We want to upload our articles automatically to eBay. The generation of the CSV file for the File Exchange Program works fine, manual uploading also works and the articles will be listed.

Now we want the software to do the upload by itself. We reference to the eBay File Exchange Guide here:
[image: here] and here:
[image: here].

This is my present code:

```php
$SOCKETPROC = fsockopen('bulksell.ebay.de', 80, $errno, $errstr, 4);

fputs($SOCKETPROC, "POST https://bulksell.ebay.de/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?FileExchangeUploadForm HTTP/1.0\r\n");
fputs($SOCKETPROC, "Connection: Keep Alive\r\n");
fputs($SOCKETPROC, "User-Agent: App v1.0\r\n");
fputs($SOCKETPROC, "Host: https://bulksell.ebay.de/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?FileExchangeUpload\r\n");
fputs($SOCKETPROC, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=THIS_STRING_SEPARATES\r\n");
fputs($SOCKETPROC, "Content-Length: " . filesize('export/ebay/items-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.csv') + filesize('export/ebay/token') . "\r\n");
fputs($SOCKETPROC, "--THIS_STRING_SEPARATES\r\n");

fputs($SOCKETPROC, "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"token\"\r\n");
fputs($SOCKETPROC, file_get_contents('export/ebay/token'));

fputs($SOCKETPROC, "\r\n--THIS_STRING_SEPARATES\r\n");

fputs($SOCKETPROC, "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"items-" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv\"\r\n");
fputs($SOCKETPROC, "Content-Type: text/csv\r\n\r\n");
fputs($SOCKETPROC, file_get_contents('export/ebay/items-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.csv'));

fputs($SOCKETPROC, "\r\n--THIS_STRING_SEPARATES\r\n");
fputs($SOCKETPROC, "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n"); // Not sure if this line is relevant

$RESULT = fgets($SOCKETPROC);
fclose($SOCKETPROC);
```

But the file just won't appear in the eBay list of uploaded files. When I change the `https://` to `http://` and checkout the result with `fgets($SOCKETPROC);` I'm getting a `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`, otherwise I don't get any reaction.

*Note:* .de is being used on purpose. So no typo or mistake there.

Answer (score 1):

Try connect and upload by cUrl:

```
$token = "your_token";
$ebay_url = "https://bulksell.ebay.de/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?FileExchangeUpload";
$sendheaders = array(
"User-Agent: MyClient v1.6",
);
$fields = array(
"token" => $token,
"file" => "@file.csv"
);

$ch = curl_init($ebay_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // set to 0 to eliminate header info from response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0); // set to 1 to eliminate body info from response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0); // use HTTP/1.0 instead of 1.1
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Returns response data instead of TRUE(1)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // uncomment this line if you get no gateway response. ###
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $sendheaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields); // use HTTP POST to send form data
$resp = curl_exec($ch); //execute post and get results
curl_close ($ch);
```